# Java and SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm attracted to the neatness that a single file database provides. What driver/connector library is out there to connect and use SQLite with Java.

I've discovered a wrapper library, [http://www.ch-werner.de/javasqlite](http://www.ch-werner.de/javasqlite/), but are there other more prominent projects available?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

The [wiki](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers) lists some more wrappers:

- Java wrapper (around a SWIG interface): http://tk-software.home.comcast.net/
- A good tutorial to use JDBC driver for SQLite. (it works at least !) http://www.ci.uchicago.edu/wiki/bin/view/VDS/VDSDevelopment/UsingSQLite
- Cross-platform JDBC driver which uses embedded native SQLite libraries on Windows, Linux, OS X, and falls back to pure Java implementation on other OSes: https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc (formerly [zentus](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc))
- Another Java - SWIG wrapper. It only works on Win32. http://rodolfo_3.tripod.com/index.html
- sqlite-java-shell: 100% pure Java port of the sqlite3 commandline shell built with NestedVM. (This is not a JDBC driver).
- SQLite JDBC Driver for Mysaifu JVM: SQLite JDBC Driver for Mysaifu JVM and SQLite JNI Library for Windows (x86) and Linux (i386/PowerPC).

Comment: My addition to this list is sqlite4java - http://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java - it's a wrapper (no JDBC); precompiled for Windows, Mac, Linux. It's simple to use and it enforces some contracts to help the developer avoid misusing SQLite.

Comment: sqlite4java looks interesting, but they also have a great comparison of the various wrappers out there: http://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/wiki/ComparisonToOtherWrappers

Comment: @kdt the problem I found with the zentus driver is that it doesn't seem to support BLOB's at all

Comment: @Martijn http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC is a fork of zentus's driver and supports BLOB (there's a short tut on their site).

Comment: http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc -> 404

Comment: @Martijn: are you sure? Because there's an open issue about it not supporting blobs (1 1/2 year later...).

Comment: @RedGlyph not anymore, haven't looked at it for ages. I know (quite sure) it bit me in the behind once.

Comment: archive.org link 
https://web.archive.org/web/20080309203650/http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers

Comment: The Xerial driver definitely supports blobs (though not the `java.sql.Blob` type). I've been using it to manage blobs for years. However, just… don't concatenate blobs; that's _horribly_ slow.

Answer (score 250):

I found your question while searching for information with [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) and Java. Just thought I'd add my answer which I also posted on my [blog](http://blog.rungeek.com/post/81611917/how-to-use-sqlite-with-java).

I have been coding in Java for a while now. I have also known about SQLite but never used it… Well I have used it through other [applications](http://www.sqlite.org/famous.html) but never in an app that I coded. So I needed it for a project this week and it's so simple use!

I found a Java JDBC driver for SQLite. Just add the [JAR file](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) to your classpath and import java.sql.*

His test app will create a database file, send some SQL commands to create a table, store some data in the table, and read it back and display on console. It will create the **test.db** file in the root directory of the project.  You can run this example with `java -cp .:sqlitejdbc-v056.jar Test`.

```
package com.rungeek.sqlite;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        stat.executeUpdate("drop table if exists people;");
        stat.executeUpdate("create table people (name, occupation);");
        PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(
            "insert into people values (?, ?);");

        prep.setString(1, "Gandhi");
        prep.setString(2, "politics");
        prep.addBatch();
        prep.setString(1, "Turing");
        prep.setString(2, "computers");
        prep.addBatch();
        prep.setString(1, "Wittgenstein");
        prep.setString(2, "smartypants");
        prep.addBatch();

        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        prep.executeBatch();
        conn.setAutoCommit(true);

        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from people;");
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("name = " + rs.getString("name"));
            System.out.println("job = " + rs.getString("occupation"));
        }
        rs.close();
        conn.close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is why I think Joel was talking bull (Google tech talk:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ) when saying that stackoverflow.com's design is better because of all the "old" posts hanging around on the internet. It's just a rehash.

Comment: Also notice that Crawshaw project seems on hiatus, but was forked and updated here: http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC

Comment: zentus.com seems broken, found mirror here; ftp://priede.bf.lu.lv/pub/DatuBazes/SQLite/SqliteJDBC/about.htm

Comment: Thanks @DanielMagnusson, you're a life saver. While on the topic, anyone still looking for the sqliteJDBC driver can go ftp://priede.bf.lu.lv/pub/DatuBazes/SQLite/SqliteJDBC/sqlitejdbc-v056.jar since the link the about.htm links to is incorrect.

Comment: maven dependency: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc

Comment: We need sqlite-jdbc on other computer? where application is being used?

Answer (score 31):

I understand you asked specifically about SQLite, but maybe [HSQL database](http://hsqldb.org/) would be a better fit with Java. It is written in Java itself, runs in the JVM, supports in-memory tables etc. and all that features make it quite usable for prototyping and unit-testing.

Comment: Yes HSQL is a very good choice and I've used it quite extensively in a couple of client apps for good effect. In this instance however, I did indeed want to use SQLite.

Answer (score 19):

David Crawshaw project(sqlitejdbc-v056.jar) seems out of date and last update was Jun 20, 2009,  [source here](https://github.com/crawshaw/sqlitejdbc)

I would recomend [Xerials fork](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC) of Crawshaw sqlite wrapper.  I replaced sqlitejdbc-v056.jar  with Xerials sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar file without any problem.

Uses same syntax as in [Bernie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/593137/63678) and is much faster and with latest sqlite library.

**What is different from Zentus's SQLite JDBC?**

> The original Zentus's SQLite JDBC driver
>   http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/ itself is an excellent utility for
>   using SQLite databases from Java language, and our SQLiteJDBC library
>   also relies on its implementation. However, its pure-java version,
>   which totally translates c/c++ codes of SQLite into Java, is
>   significantly slower compared to its native version, which uses SQLite
>   binaries compiled for each OS (win, mac, linux).
>
> To use the native version of sqlite-jdbc, user had to set a path to
>   the native codes (dll, jnilib, so files, which are JNDI C programs) by
>   using command-line arguments, e.g., -Djava.library.path=(path to the
>   dll, jnilib, etc.), or -Dorg.sqlite.lib.path, etc. This process was
>   error-prone and bothersome to tell every user to set these variables.
>   Our SQLiteJDBC library completely does away these inconveniences.
>
> Another difference is that we are keeping this SQLiteJDBC libray
>   up-to-date to the newest version of SQLite engine, because we are one
>   of the hottest users of this library. For example, SQLite JDBC is a
>   core component of UTGB (University of Tokyo Genome Browser) Toolkit,
>   which is our utility to create personalized genome browsers.

**EDIT** : As usual when you update something, there will be problems in some obscure place in your code(happened to me). Test test test =)

Comment: The `sqlite-jdbc` project is great, but be aware that it is [Apache licensed](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt). Therefore you must give attribution if you use it, whether your code is FOSS or proprietary.

Answer (score 16):

There is a new project [SQLJet](http://sqljet.com/) that is a pure Java implementation of SQLite. It doesn't support all of the SQLite features yet, but may be a very good option for some of the Java projects that work with SQLite databases.

Comment: It looks promising but it appears that it doesn't offer an SQL query ability yet, kind of a deal breaker for me.

Comment: Still does not support SQL queries, rather, a lower level API.

Comment: Still very useful for applications where you only need to _generate_ SQLite files, i.e., don't need SQL to query the data.

Answer (score 3):

When you compile and run the code, you should set the classpath options value.
Just like the following:

```
javac -classpath .;sqlitejdbc-v056.jar Text.java

java -classpath .;sqlitejdbc-v056.jar Text
```

Please pay attention to "." and the sparate ";"(win, the linux is ":")

Answer (score 3):

sqlitejdbc code can be downloaded using git from https://github.com/crawshaw/sqlitejdbc.

```
# git clone https://github.com/crawshaw/sqlitejdbc.git sqlitejdbc
...
# cd sqlitejdbc
# make
```

Note: Makefile requires curl binary to download sqlite libraries/deps.

Answer (score 2):

The example code leads to a memory leak in Tomcat (after undeploying the webapp, the classloader still remains in memory) which will cause an `outofmemory` eventually. The way to solve it is to use the [sqlite-jdbc-3.7.8.jar](http://www.xerial.org/maven/repository/snapshot/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.7.8-SNAPSHOT/); it's a snapshot, so it doesn't appear for maven yet.

Answer (score 0):

Typo: `java -cp .:sqlitejdbc-v056.jar Test`

should be: `java -cp .:sqlitejdbc-v056.jar; Test`

notice the semicolon after ".jar" i hope that helps people, could cause a lot of hassle

Comment: Care to elaborate? On *nix the ; will seperate the java from the Test command (and therefore create a error). On Windows the : wont work as a cp seperator. So all in all `.:xxx.jar;` does not make sense. And you also need to specify the package name for the Test class.