# HSQLDB SQLException: Out of memory establishing database connection

Tags: java, hsqldb

We have a desktop application with a local HSQLDB database. Some customers have reported their application stops working. When I try to open it with DbVisualizer I can see this on debug console:

```
12:45:32 [DEBUG pool-2-thread-1 D.?] RootConnection:     jdbcDriver.connect("jdbc:hsqldb:C:\test\database.db", {user=**, password=})
java.sql.SQLException: error in script file line: 56 out of memory
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.onseven.dbvis.d.B.D.?(Z:1548)
    at com.onseven.dbvis.d.B.F$A.call(Z:278)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Anybody knows something to do to open this and analyze what is the problem?

Answer (score 7):

Usually, this exception occurs when the database is corrupted. Try with a backup of the database. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144638/am-i-crazy-switching-an-established-product-from-hsqldb-to-apache-derby) for another discussion regarding this topic.

Comment: Hi Ingo, thanks for your answer. I'm trying to discover if there is a way to analyze a corrupted database, nor preventing this.

Comment: I don't think there is such a tool.

Comment: No, there is not. If you have the database ".script" file, it may be possible to fix it manually if the corruption is small and located... Do copies, edit and try to load. After a while you may give up. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error when opening an HSQLDB database using an incompatible driver version. For example, I receive it when using version `2.2.8` to open an HSQLDB database saved with version `1.8.1.3`. I use [SQuirrel](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) to view these databases and must set up a few different drivers to support each version. I imagine [DB Visualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) has a similar capability.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that if the database is very large that you allocate more memory to the heap. see [Java heap space out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748432/java-heap-space-out-of-memory)