# Pure java sqlite library?

Tags: java

I saw [Java and SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite), but what ones are made in pure java and are platform independent? Also which would be the best to start with? I have never used sqlite but I assume it is like mysql. Also do any of them come with a nice command line tool for testing queries?

Comment: Given that SQLite has no database server, wouldn't a Type 4 JDBC driver mean that you'd have to port 100% of SQLite to Java?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SQLite is getting quite a lot of hype in other language domains, however with Java you have something else available:

- [HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org/) (*more commonly known as HSQLDB*) is pure Java RDBMS which is specialized around running it as part of your application meaning that you can embed it to your software and it just works.
- [H2](http://www.h2database.com) is a complete rewrite of HypersonicSQL (*common ancestor for H2 and HyperSQL*) and is also fully Java. One nice feature of this one is RDBMS emulation which allows it to function with SQL written specifically for, say, Oracle RDBMS.
- There's also the almost mandatory Apache Commons variation too, [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/). As with the other two, Derby is also embeddable and has a small JAR file size footprint.

As for tools, well, that varies a lot. Most of the Hypersonic family products for example are mainly meant for unit testing which means that you can unit test your DB Schemas and actual queries quite easily with (*almost*) plain Java code.

Answer (score 4):

[sqljet](http://sqljet.com/), which in contradiction to the name does not have SQL, but can use SQLlite databases.

Answer (score 3):

And updated answer, you may want to try [Xerial's Sqlite JDBC driver](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/overview). While its current version is not pure-java, it packages binaries for major operating systems so that it is mostly portable.

Also sqlite4java also currently packages binaries for major OSes.