# How can I connect to a SQLite data source using JDBC on Debian/ARM?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, arm

I'm attempting to port a small Java application to a Debian Linux environment running on an ARM processor (specifically, a Freescale i.MX28 CPU with an ARM926EJ-S core).

The application persists data to a local SQLite database, and has been tested and works on Windows 7/Intel and Ubuntu 14.x/Intel with OpenJDK JRE versions 1.6 - 1.8.

However, on the Debian/ARM machine, it core dumps when it tries to make a connection to the database.

For example, this line, using the xerial jdbc driver:

```
    ConnectionSource connectionSource = 
        new JdbcConnectionSource("jdbc:sqlite:" + path);
```

I've tried other drivers, which have similar behaviors, and to my surprise neither the great google machine or SO have any definitive answers - though [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550598/does-not-load-jdbc-library-on-arm-by-execute-java-applikation) are certainly having similar [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169315/how-can-i-deploy-sqlite-in-winrt-devices-with-an-arm-cpu).

I don't think it's an issue with SQLite on the ARM itself... I can get a SQLite command prompt and run queries as expected manually.

So what big obvious thing am I overlooking? There's no market for JDBC/SQLite on Debian/ARM? Xerial works great but I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Would any of the down/close voters care to say why this is a bad question? It's programming related, it's specific, I've demonstrated that I did research before asking.

Comment: I can tell you that 2 downvotes are for "off-topic to ask for library, tool ...". I won't personnally vote to close because your question is indeed specific, but it is just my opinion. Unfortunately, I cannot answer :-(

Comment: Perhaps I should change the title... I agree that asking for tool recommendations is off topic... I'm just not sure how to describe the programming problem I'm having without referencing that part.