# SQLITE with Java against property files

Tags: java, sqlite

I have in my Java app lot off properties that I store in property files ( I read them a ot and write a lot, app is some sort of ide for microprocessors,lot off users can have lot of projects with lot off properties ). I heard something about SQLITE and my question is : Can I use SQLITE and not to use those properties files, but that user doesn't have installed SQLITE server ? Does SQLITE require lot of memory ( if not to put inside installer installation for SQLITE if needed ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as "SQLite server", it's totally embedded fast lightweight DBMS that you can include within your app distribution. It's originally written in C but you can use [SQLiteJDBC](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC) which includes several native implementations of SQLite as well as 100% pure Java implementation which runs on any platform.

Answer (score 1):

There is no server component for SQLite. It's just a lightweight library that you can use to manipulate a file containing the database.

See this question about libraries for using SQLite in Java: [Java and SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use SQL DB then I think you'd be better off using java embedded DB like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html). It's lightweight, fast and easier to embed into a java application (just another jar file).