# read SQLite db file using java

Tags: java, sqlite

I want to read a SQLite db file using Java. Will you please tell me how to read it?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite

Answer (score 10):

[First read these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite)

David Crawshaw developed a JAR file (still available on [github here](https://github.com/crawshaw/sqlitejdbc) but not touched for 10+ years). Taro Saito has a self-contained straightforward JAR file [available on github here](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) that includes the JDBC driver and the native runtimes required. Just add this JAR file to your classpath and import java.sql.*

David's test app will create a database file, send some SQL commands to create a table, store some data in the table, and read it back and display on console. It will create the test.db file in the root directory of the project.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        stat.executeUpdate("drop table if exists people;");
        stat.executeUpdate("create table people (name, occupation);");
        PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(
            "insert into people values (?, ?);");

        prep.setString(1, "Gandhi");
        prep.setString(2, "politics");
        prep.addBatch();
        prep.setString(1, "Turing");
        prep.setString(2, "computers");
        prep.addBatch();
        prep.setString(1, "Wittgenstein");
        prep.setString(2, "smartypants");
        prep.addBatch();

        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        prep.executeBatch();
        conn.setAutoCommit(true);

        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from people;");
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("name = " + rs.getString("name"));
            System.out.println("job = " + rs.getString("occupation"));
        }
        rs.close();
        conn.close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: unLuckly, the link is not found now, try this: https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc

Answer (score 3):

The Java JDBC driver for SQLLite is on the [David Crawshaw](http://www.zentus.com/) site http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/ Add the jar file to your class path and import java.sql.* and you should be good.