# Is there an open source alternative to MS SQL Compact Edition for Remote Data Application?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, open-source, sql-server-ce

We currently use SQL CE databases on the client machines, which then synchronise their data to a central server using the merge replication/RDA functionality of MS SQL. The amounts of data involved is small, and the central server will often be idle for ~95% of the time - it's only active really when data is incoming, and is typically synchronised on a daily/weekly basis.

The SQL Standard licensing costs for this are large, relative to the SQL server workload / the amount of data we're talking about (in the order of 100s of MBs maximum). What I'd like to know is if there's an open source alternative (mySQL or similar) which we could use as the backend data storage for our .NET application. My background is Windows Server Admin, so relatively new to Linux, but happy to give it a go and learn some new skills, as long as it won't be prohibitively difficult. If there are any other alternatives that would be great too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is quite a open ended question so I am going to give you some guidelines around what you can start researching.

- Client Side embeded databases.
  MySQL can be embedded just from my understanding MySQL as a embedded server might be overkill for a client.There are however a stack of alternatives. Once such a point would be the Berkely database system. There are other alternatives as well. Keep in mind you dont want a FULL sql server on the client side you are looking for something light weight.You can read about Berkley here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB and about alternatives here : [Single-file, persistent, sorted key-value store for Java (alternative to Berkeley DB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032581/alternatives-to-berkeley-db-java). They mention SQLite which might just be up your alley. So in short there is a whole stack of open source tools you can use here.
- Back End Databases. MySQL will do the job very well and even PostgreSQL. PostegreSQL seems to support more enterprise features the last time I looked however that might have changed. These two are your main players in the SQL server market as far as open source is concerned. Either one will do fine in your scenario. Both PostgreSQL and MySQL run on windows as well so you dont have to install Linux though I would suggest that you invest the time in Linux as I have it is well worth the effort and the peace of mind you get is good.

There is one major sticking point for you if you switch over to MySQL/PostgreSQL that the current RDA/replication technology you have will not be supported by these databases and you will need to look at how to implement this probably from scratch. So while the backend and even front end DB's can be replaced the replication of the data will be a little more problematic but NOT impossible.

Go play with these technologies do some tests and then you will need to decide how you will replace that replication.

Comment: I'm coming at it from an infrastructure perspective mainly - if I do the research and find something viable then our developers can have a go at making it work with our software. Thanks for the suggestions I'll follow them up.