# Simple in app data store solution

Tags: java, local-storage

Looking for an all in one solution that I can distribute within my Java application to store a small amount of data as records. This data can change over time and will be updated frequently. It stores book information - author, genre, title, rating etc.

I would like to have something that will allow me to look into full text searching on a particular table, searching is something that will be crucial.

The only real requirement outside of the searching abilities is minimal setup, I dont expect MySQL etc to be running as a service, so the solution needs minimal attention form the end user.

So far I have been looking at SQLLITE.

As for the searching its totally new to me, one of the reasons I am doing this project is so I can learn about it.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: [JavaDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) doesn't meet your requirements?

Comment: Some discussion here might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite

Answer (score 0):

You can look at HSQLDB that is the closest thing to sqlite, and is very simple (there are three storage: in memory, in a local file, in a distant server).

It can works with apache Lucene to get a full text search.