# Find the counts of all intersections in k-dimensions

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, theory

Given an input set **S** of **k-dimensional** axis aligned rectangles, I would like to find **all the k-dimensional intervals** on which **at least** 2 k-dimensional rectangles **overlap**. If more than 2 k-dimensional rectangles overlap, I would like to **find the count** of how many were overlapping on each of such regions.

Edit:
I have done this in 1D and 2D using Klee's Measure and the Line Sweep Algorithm. I am confused about how to get it beyond 2 dimensions.

Comment: And I want a puppy:) So what have you done so far? Maybe first try to do this for the 1D/2D/3D, that should not be to hard. Than try work out a general case, for higher dimensions.

Comment: This post http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138635/hyperrectangle-partition-of-set-of-overlapping-hyperrectangles should get you started

Comment: Gijs, I have edited my question. Hope it makes it clear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008206/detect-overlapping-of-rectangular-prisms Maybe look at this one for 3D case. And i think you should look into the link I already posted. Thats is about the k-dimensional case...duplicate?

Comment: What are your time complexity requirements? The brute force solution seems pretty easy.