# How to create a table into SQLite from a CSV file in Java?

Tags: java, sqlite, csv

I have to read the headers of the file in order to create a table in a database with the name of the columns specified on the CSV file.

For instance:
[image]

the program has to create a table on the database like this:

```
create table csv_ejemplo (
unit varchar(255),
line varchar(255),
total_time varchar(255),
ocurrences varchar(255),
text varchar(255)
);
```

Finally, I have to iterate over every column and insert that value into the recently created table.

How could I do this? Should I use reflection? I'm confused because I don't know if the database must be created first outside Java (I mean, through SQLite).

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQLite Database can also be created by Java, check [this older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite).

A CSV-file is normally delimited by some kind of char (like `,`), so you would simply read the file line by line (using `BufferedReader` or something) and then split the line-string up by using the [`split()`-method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

I guess, the first line of your CSV-File contains some informations about the column-names. So, you'll want to take it's informations to create the Database first and then itterate over the rest to get the values.

To insert the values in the Database, I would use a `PreparedStatement`, as illustrated in the linked topic.