# How to Bind MySql Database inside a JAR file of any application?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have prepared an application that is a small demo of Student information manipulation. I have stored information related to students in a MySQL DB. Now my application is working 100% on my computer. But I want that work everywhere without depending on Database! I mean I just want "**WHEREVER MY .JAR FILE GOES, DATABASE SHOULD ALSO GO ALONG WITH THAT INSIDE .JAR FILE** "

So anyone who is using my application or trying it, they can realize exact result of this application.

How can I make this possible? Please someone help me.

Comment: Note - people here can read questions just fine. Please do away with the bold caps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably need to look at something like [HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org/), which is a in-memory database (which you will need to populate at application start-up). Or have a look at [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), which is an embedded databsase, which you can distribute as a resource in your jar.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work. MySQL is a full-blown RDBMS. You would have to install it on every computer if you want application to use it locally. An alternative would be using [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

> SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine.

[SQLite and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite)

SQLite seems to be a good fit for your requirements.

Comment: It's actually a bit finicky to use a SQLite database with(in) a JAR ... this is because SQLite requires direct-file access. The actual distribution of the SQLite library is easy.