# Suitable database for application

Tags: java, database

I need to find a suitable database for my application, that satisfy following criteria,

1. Zero intallation
2. Zero configuration
3. Portable (client wants database file to be able to shift from one machine to another manually.)

Please suggest me a suitable database for the above criteria.

Answer (score 1):

For java I will go with Apache Derby (aka Java DB).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [JavaDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html), you can use it as an in process database and it has good performance. I have used it in several projects, mainly in Java Swing desktop applications.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommand [h2](http://www.h2database.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) for that.

Have a look at [Java and SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite) for how to interact with the SQLite databae from Java.

Answer (score 0):

for me [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial) also meets these criteria (unless you really need sql database)