# How to install SQLite database on the WIndows XP system

Tags: java, sqlite

I want to connect my java program to the SQLite db. What are necessary steps that I have to follow. I want to install sqlite database on my system to access the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [SQLite Homepage](http://www.sqlite.org/about.html):

> SQLite is a in-process library that implements a self-contained,
>   serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine.
>   [...]
>
> SQLite is an embedded SQL database engine. Unlike most other SQL
>   databases, SQLite does not have a separate server process. SQLite
>   reads and writes directly to ordinary disk files. A complete SQL
>   database with multiple tables, indices, triggers, and views, is
>   contained in a single disk file.

So you don't actually *install* SQLite. To create and work with SQLite Databases, you can use the provided [`sqlite-shell`](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html), which is a command-line tool. If you are familiar with SQL, this should not be a problem.

Although, there are also some GUI-tools out there to work with SQLite...

If you want your Java-application to access and work with an SQLite Database, you'll need the necessary drivers. A nice topic on this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite).

Answer (score 1):

Hello mayur rahatekar,

Here's a quick tutorial for creating a sqlitedb on your computer, its explained from the ground of:
[SQLiteDB with some Androidflavour](http://computersight.com/computers/android-and-sqlite-using-database/)

Best Regards

safari

Comment: Thanks a lot to your reply. I want to connect SQLite database to the Pure java program.So Can I have to Install SQLite database on my system. Is their any exe file which will Install SQL Lite database on the System.

Comment: yes there is use the sqllite browser: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/ if you found the answer good please +1 and the green tick ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can take the help of mozilla firefox browser.If you have then you can search on google how to integrate sqlite with mozilla.it's very easy.Click [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) to see the link.