# Native Database Support in Java?

Tags: java, database

Does Java have support for any form of databases natively? That is, does Java have a set of API or library that allows me to create and use databases such as MS Access or SQLite, etc?

It seems like I must download a third-party wrapper library or driver before I can use any database. IS there a native standard library in Java that allows me to do databases without third-party classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Java's database functionality (JDBC) is composed of a set of interfaces (plus a few utility classes) in the standard library and third-party implementations of those interfaces that let you connect to all the various databases out there. You'll have to find and use at least a driver library for any database you'd like to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

[This link is a quick overview of them](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136101.html)

- JavaDB - a Java-based database
- JDO - Java DataObject Objects - an abstraction for persistence
- JDBC - Java Database Connectivity - which has drivers for many vendor DBs (MySQL, MSSQL, SQLite, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

There are many 100% Java databases. Start with Apache Derby.

Obviously, if you want to talk to a database that is, itself, not written in Java, you'll have to use some sort of connector.

In many cases, for databases typically spoken to over a network (e.g. Oracle, mysql, postgresql) the connector is a 'type 4' JDBC driver, which is a slug of 100% Java code that implements the same network protocol as gets used for all other programming languages.

For embedded non-Java databases, 'some glue required'.

Answer (score 0):

The standard class library doesn't have any thing like that built in. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite) for information on getting SQLite going with minimum fuss. That's as good as it's going to get, I'm afraid.