# How should I make a simple database of names?

Tags: java, database, web

I am currently working on a simple web-based program involving a user typing in a word in a client program(written in Java), and sending the word and other basic information to a database.  I am finished with the word typing portion, but I have no idea what to do about the database.  What software should I use for the database?  Here are the requirements that I need for the database:

- Read/Write Functionality
- Java compatibility
- Easy to use/set up
- Has plenty of tutorials/documentation

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that this is either a dev experiment or a school project. If this is something you're playing with I think the easiest/quickest would be to go with Sqlite. Here is some info on using it with Java: [Java and SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite)

If it is something you intend to deploy in a production environment then go with mysql and jdbc.

Answer (score 0):

How about [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/)?

Its very simple, extremely well supported and if you need to do some more advanced SQL queries it can do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use MySQL and a JDBC driver for communicating with it. The trick is to Google

> java mysql jdbc

That should give a lot of usefull results. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just learning about databases and getting started, nothing is simpler than an sqlite database since it's actually nothing more than a static file. Here is a jdbc driver for it: http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/

Comment: Good advice, I was typing mine as your answer came in :)