# create and use database in developing java desktop application

Tags: java, database, netbeans

I am trying to create a java desktop application based on a database. But what i want is that the database that i use should be included with the installation files that are created after building the project so that the user does not have to install any database separately to use the application.

Can anyone please help me with this and also show how to go about it?

Comment: What about Apache Derby or Microsoft Access?

Comment: Embedded Derby or HyperionSQL?

Comment: embedded derby??? how do i use it???

Comment: @user2509932 please check [**this link**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12158722/1563878), its a similar question: "Java Desktop Application using SQLite installed by a single installer"

Answer (score 1):

A good option is for your application to use an embedded database.  Which is where the database process runs within the same process as the application using it.  From a code-perspective, it still acts like any other database (accessed through connections/datasources, for example).  So the code doesn't know it's an embedded database.

There are lots of database products that supported embedded databases...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database

I've used H2 previously with good results, so I can recommend that product for use as an embedded database.  You should look at what your needs are and see if there is a product which can be embedded which fits your requirements.