# java me database and floggy

Tags: database, java-me, gis, mobile-application

I'm developing a gis java me mobile application and I need simple database to store my ATM and bank branch for a simple search on map. I decide to use floggy as database.
Does any body know better database for my situation?

Comment: Do you need to perform spatial queries? ST_Distance, ST_Intersects, etc.?

Comment: No,we have 1000 points that includes branches and ATM_POS, I don't need spatial queries, it's a simple offline application shows these branches and ATM_POS on map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its an offline database (as in, stored with the application) then why not SQLite? It can store spatial data in WKB (Well Known Binary - the standard) and has [quite a lot of java wrappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite).
Then if you do want to do spatial queries in the future, you can [update to SpatiaLite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite/).

Comment: because the number of branches and ATM_POS weren't many I used cvs , tnX for your help