# Java easiest way to persist data across launches

Tags: java, persistence

just learning java and need to build a program that can store simple objects between launches. What is the easiest way to do that?

So If I add 10 strings to an array, close the program, and open the program again, I should just be able to print those 10 objects again.

I imagin I need to store those objects in some sort of way.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you heard about `static` or `enum`? Maybe a properties file and load the data in a `static` context?

Comment: what about serialization. ?

Comment: Learning java tools on eclipse, so prob the most basi. This is a very small intro program

Comment: Maybe when downvotting you could explain why, not sure it adds anything to the community bust downvoting an answer

Comment: @Will i'm not from the downvoters but you didn't comment on any ans so how can we help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be using Serializable although it is, imho, the ugliest way. And if your project is going to evolve, it will be a huge hindrance.

Another way would be XML, it's not very hard to use.

What's lightweight and solid, and also rather easy to use, is SQLite. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/593137/1527244) for more details.

Another way would be `Preferences`, but those are, as the name says, for simple preferences, not for actual data or profiles, so they shouldn't contain too much information.

Comment: I think the serialization will be best i read about xserial (i think). Is there anything built in in version 6 that i can call? Im not familiar with java libraries yet, but working on it. Thanks

Comment: just for persistence using DB is not a good idea.

Comment: True, but I was implying if he needed to start with little data and that data would soon become large - DB would be the way to go. And SQLite as lightweight single user DB is really viable.

Answer (score 3):

i don't know what is easy for you but the serialization is best way of doing this.

Comment: you know why I upvoted you!

Comment: i upvoted everone who says serialization within 2 mins.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way: [serialization.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) in my opinion.

Comment: same thinking! hope he finds it easy ;)+1

Answer (score 1):

You could store them in a text file or use a free database tool like SQLite or SQL Express to store the data. Using a text file might be the easiest way to do this.

Here is a link to help you with reading/writing in a text file : http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42

If you need more help just ask !