# Database for java project

Tags: java, database, ms-access

I have developed a Java project using MS-Access as database .
This project reads log files , and generate reports.
I have to migrate this project  to a UNIX server .Can somebody please suggest me another suite of database for my project. or If I should continue using MS-access

Comment: sqlplus / mysql are good databases that you could user for similar project. I have used them for something similar in past.

Comment: You could use a pure Java database like Derby or H2; then it would work on multiple platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your needs, you may consider SQLITE (for a small project) or MySQL (for a medium one) - both are straightforward to install and use.
For SQLite: [Java and SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite) and for MySQL there is a nice tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html
Good luck!