# Java: How to extract matching lines from a large text file fast?

Tags: java, performance, text-files, large-files, fasta

Although aware that there are plenty of offered solutions to my problem *in general*, 
I am still not satisfied with the runtime they require in my *special* case.

Consider a **35G** large **text file** in FASTA format, like this:

```
>Protein_1 So nice and cute little fella
MTTKKCLQKFHLESLGKLGDSFLKYAISIQLFKSYENHYEGLPSIKKNKIISNAALFKLG 
YARKILRFIRNEPFDLKVGLIPSDNSQAYNFGKEFLMPSVKMCSRVK*
>Protein_2 Fancy incredible description of its function
MADDSKFCFFLVSTFLLLAVVVNVTLAANYVPGDDILLNCGGPDNLPDADGRKWGTDIGS
[…] etc.
```

I need to extract the `>` lines *only*.

Using `grep '>' proteins.fasta > protein_descriptions.txt` to achieve this takes only a couple of minutes.

But using Java 7 this is now already running for over 90 minutes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader fastaIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    String str;
    while ((str = fastaIn.readLine()) != null) {
        if (str.startsWith(">")) {
            l.append(str);
        }
    }
    fastaIn.close();
    // …
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to speed this up to `grep` performance?

Your help will be much appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: Have you considered the idea of just calling 'grep' as external process? Just read the output file / stdout and you have almost the same performance.

Comment: I would try to implement some SAX or StAX parser.

Comment: Dear Alessandro I did consider using `grep` as an external process, but this has to run also on Windows.

Comment: Hi Scadge! Are you sure a SAX or StAX parser speeds up the process?

Comment: It may be out of context of this question, but is there any append() method in List interface in JAVA? I think you have only add() method to put objects in ArrayList Object. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you write it to the outfile immediatelly instead of accumulating objects in the memory it will improve performance (and will be more like what you did with grep anyway).

```
...
BufferedWriter fastaOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]));
...
while ((str = fastaIn.readLine()) != null) {
        if (str.startsWith(">")) {
            fastaOut.write(str);
            fastaOut.newLine();
        }
    }
...    
fastaOut.close();
```

Comment: Why was this answer down-voted?  I'm pretty sure it is the solution.  If your file is 35 GiB, you'll meed *a whole lot* of memory for your `ArrayList`.  In the worst case, this will blow up your physical memory and your OS starts swapping.  And when that happens, performance degrades tremendously.  But even if your memory is large enough, the JVM's performance might well drop as it gets more and more work to do with memory management and garbage collection.  Use your OS statistics to find out how much memory and CPU your process is using.

Comment: I do see your point. My use case though is a little more complicated. I would want to store the List of protein descriptions using `ObjectOutputStream` in order to enable loading it extremely quickly afterwards. How should I do that?

Comment: If you are hitting the physical limit of your RAM size, you'll have to abandon the idea of holding all data in memory at a single point of time because no matter what format you are using, it will be extremely slow.  Maybe using a database (eg [SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite)) could help?  But first you should go and check your process' resource consumption as I've suggested.

Comment: If you know the size of the file that you got from grep, then you can use StringBuffer or StringBuilder wisely. Alternatively use the method mentioned above and then read in the new output file.

Answer (score 1):

The [biojava.org](https://github.com/biojava/biojava/blob/master/biojava3-core/src/main/java/org/biojava3/core/sequence/io/FastaReader.java) provides a fasta reader. 
For reading huge files you would have to consider using a [SeekableByteChannell](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel.html) and using the ByteBuffers. 
The biojava library uses bytebuffers.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably speed this up considerably using multiple threads. If the file is X bytes long, and you have n threads, you start each thread at X/n intervals, and read X/n bytes. You will want to synchronize your ArrayList to ensure your results are added correctly

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. But how do I ensure that I split the file into chunks that end at a line break exactly. Otherwise I could miss at least part of protein description, couldn't I?

Comment: Your search string is only 2 characters... You could just start at X/n - 1 and read X/n + 2 characters; that should deal with this case