# JDBC and SQLite - No suitable driver found no matter what I try

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I try to make a simple Java program and connect to a SQLite database for learning purposes. But no matter what I try I cannot succeed. I always get `No suitabe driver found for jdbc:sqlite:database.db`. And yet it should be so simple. I have already tried numerous drivers from [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc).

I have read up and I understand the theory: The JDBC API deals with the communication to the JDBC manager, while the JDBC driver deals with the communication to the database. I also understand that I have to add a classpath to the .jar file containing the database driver when I run the compiled class file. [As explained here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite).

Some tutorials claim there is a need to register the driver with `Class.forName()` but [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) says:

> Applications no longer need to explicitly load JDBC drivers using Class.forName()]

Also, the SQLite tutorials that I have followed never register the driver before running `DriverManager.getConnection(url);` [Example sqlitetutorial.net](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/)

In my directory `E:\Project`I have these files:

```
DataBase.java
DataBase.class
database.db
sqlite-jdbc-3.44.1.0.jar
```

When I run the compiled class file, I use `java -cp ".;sqlite-jdbc-3.44.1.0.jar" DataBase` in the terminal window (Powershell)

And here is my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DataBase {
    public static void connect() {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:database.db";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            
            System.out.println("Connection is established");
            
            conn.close();
            System.out.println("Connection closed.");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    } // End method connect

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         connect();

    } // End of main method
} // End of class
```

I would appreciate any help I could get to push me forward.

I suppose it has to do with the .jar file not being found but I have tried every possible way: Putting copies of the .jar file everywhere in different directories, renaming it to make it simpler, adding multiple directories when adding the class path, etc. I have no clue left of what could be missing.

Also, when I try to do the same in VSCode, by adding the .jar file under "referenced libraries", it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the SQLite JDBC driver also requires the `slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar`, as detailed in the README on its [GitHub repository](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc):

> 1. [Download](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc#download) sqlite-jdbc-3.44.1.0.jar then append this jar file into your classpath.
> 2. [Download](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.36/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar) slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar then append this jar file into your classpath.
> 3. Open a SQLite database connection from your code. (see the example below)
>
> ##### Example usage
>
> Assuming `sqlite-jdbc-3.44.1.0.jar` and `slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar` are
> placed in the current directory.
>
> ```bash
> > javac Sample.java
> > java -classpath ".;sqlite-jdbc-3.44.1.0.jar;slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar" Sample   # in Windows
> ```

In other words, you need to also put `slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar` in that directory and use:

```
java -cp ".;sqlite-jdbc-3.44.1.0.jar;slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar" DataBase
```

On my machine this will make it work:

```
D:\temp> java -cp ".;sqlite-jdbc-3.44.1.0.jar;slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar" DataBase
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Connection is established
Connection closed.
```

If you had explicitly added a `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")` to your application, you would have been able to diagnose this, because without the `slf4-api-1.7.36.jar` that would result in (I added `Class.forName` to the `main`):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at org.sqlite.JDBC.<clinit>(JDBC.java:26)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
        at DataBase.main(DataBase.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
        ... 4 more
```

So, although explicit loading of the driver is no longer needed, it can give additional troubleshooting information.

Comment: Yes! It solved it! Thank you! But it's so strange that several tutorials skipped the part of slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar for example https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/ Is it even possible that it could have worked for them without this second .jar file?

Comment: @Fivi The introduction of a dependency on slf4j is very recent, in [version 3.43.2.0](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/releases/tag/3.43.2.0). Likely most tutorials are based on older versions. Personally, as a maintainer of another JDBC driver, I would not have done this, and instead used `java.util.logging` (built-in in Java), or `System.Logger` (also built-in in Java, but requires Java 9 or higher).

Comment: @Fivi For example, the tutorial you linked uses version 3.27.2.1, which did not yet have this dependency. BTW: This is also a good reason why you should use a build tool like Maven or Gradle: those would have pulled in the additional dependency automatically as it is declared in the [pom.xml of SQLlite 3.44.1.0](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.44.1.0).

Comment: I see, interesting development! I'm learning a lot here so thank you all for the answers, @Mark Rotteveel. From now on I will make sure to always read the Readme files when I troubleshoot.